# Case Condition not working on date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with data like this:

```
Date
-------
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
2012-02-02 00:00:00.000
2012-02-03 00:00:00.000
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

I need a query, whenever `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` appears, I need the retrieve column as `''`, other values need to be same

```
Select  case 
When CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),app.LastActivityDate,101) = '1900-01-01'  THEN ''
End as [Last Activity Date] from t_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Select  case 
When app.LastActivityDate = cast('19000101' as datetime)
THEN ''
ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),app.LastActivityDate,101)
End as [Last Activity Date] from t_name
```